# How do I use GMP properly to do this operation?

Tags: c++, gmp

My code in C++

```
   long long N=1000000000000LL;
   long long a = N;
   mpz_class v;
   mpz_mul(v, a, a); 
   cout<<v<<endl; //I want this to show 1000000000002000000000001
   long long U=((sqrt(4*N+v)-1)/4);  //not sure how to do this in GMP at all
   cout << U << endl; //should show 250000000000
```

This is a snippet that shows what kind of operations I want to do. But I am not experienced enough with GMP to get it down, and the documentation is unclear to me. How do I correct all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mpz_class has [no constructor from long long](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers) (it only goes up to unsigned long), so you'd have to use an intermediate string:

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    long long N = 1000000000000LL;
    mpz_class a(std::to_string(N).c_str());
    mpz_class v = a*a;
    std::cout << v << '\n'; // shows 1000000000000000000000000
    std::cout << (a+1) * (a+1) << '\n'; // THIS shows 1000000000002000000000001

    mpz_class U = ((sqrt(4*a+v)-1)/4);
    std::cout << U << '\n'; // shows 250000000000
}
```

Comment: Also do I use mpz_t or mpz_class?

Comment: @KaLiMa mpz_class is natural for a C++ program. mpz_t can always be accessed with [get_mpz_t()](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-General)

Comment: For some reason that string line isn't working for me -- any reason? "to_string is not a member of std"

Comment: @KaLiMa your compiler might be too old to support it -- just start with `"1000000000000"`, the string.

Comment: Any reason why L=ceil((sqrt(v-4*N)-1)/4)-1; would throw "eval" errors?